# How to remove Error: OK from contact form

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I am using a responsive contact form I purchased from here: http://www.freecontactform.com/responsive_form.php

I made only a few minor changes to it as you can see in the attached picture [Contact form changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdNM4.png)

The form works. The anti-spam works and messages go through. The problem is when a message is sent, this message appears under the Submit button:

> Sorry, there was a problem sending your message.
>   Error: OK.
>   Thank you, we've received your message.

The message does go through. But having that response pop up can be confusing to people sending a message. I have no clue as to what the error is. I have reached out to the creators of the contact form for help but it has been several days with no reply. Can anyone at least tell me what the error might be and, if possible, how to fix it?

Here is the full code for that section, I am not very familiar with JavaScript so I am unsure of what I can safely remove to get that error message removed:

```
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize()
        });

        $('#contactForm').hide();
        $('#status').html("Sending form, please wait...");

        request.done(function(e) {
            if(e[0] + e[1] == "OK") {
                $('#status').html("Thank you, we've received your message.");
            } else {
                $('#status').html("Sorry, there was a problem sending your message.<br>Error: " + e);
                $('#contactForm').show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: We would likely need to see the form's code, but you're likely not allowed to post their code. Our help may be limited, though I would think you could search the file for the error to possibly find the reference?

Comment: Of the code that I am allowed to edit, I see no error. There are multiple files with the form that I can view but not edit. Since I cannot edit them, and I made only minor changes to the appearance of the form, I do not understand why there is an error in the first place. Hence why I asked the creators for help. I was curious if anyone here would have an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: Looking at the page source on their site, there is a `<div id="status"></div>` below the form (which will appear below the submit button), and there is jQuery in the page that populates the div via `$('#status')` handling, but I don't see anything with the `Error:` string. If you can open your browser's developer tools, to see if you are getting any console errors from the page after submit?

Comment: I tried what you suggested and no console errors appear.

Comment: Of course what they show on the site, and what you have, might be two different things (possibly). You should at least be able to find the message: `Thank you, we've received your message` in the file?  Can you paste the entire line in a comment?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I was able to find this in a file that I am allowed to edit:  request.done(function(e) {
                if(e[0] + e[1] == "OK") {
                    $('#status').html("Thank you, we've received your message.");
                } else {
                    $('#status').html("Sorry, there was a problem sending your message.<br>Error: " + e);
                    $('#contactForm').show();
                }
            });

Comment: If I was to just to remove the error message, would that be alright since the messages are still going through?

Comment: Could you try to see what the `e[0]` and `e[1]` might contain to be OK, before I'd try to alter too much?  Oh, by the way, that is not the same handling that appears when viewing the browser source at their site.

Comment: I added the code above. I am unsure as to what e[0] and e[1] are referring to.

Comment: What you can do, is before the if condition with `e[0]`, add: `alert(e[0]); alert(e[1]);` and see what appears in the popups for those two values. Alternatively, you may be able to set a break point on the if  condition in the developer tools as well, and then hover those two variables to see their values.

Comment: After adding the alerts, when I tried sending a message, all that popped up was a box saying "the website name" says it's ok. I had to press a button that said ok a couple times before the message would send. And I still get the same error message after sending.

Comment: Ok, then instead of the alerts, replace those with two with console logs:  `console.log('e0: ' + e[0]); console.log('e1: ' + e[1]);` ... and then check the console in the developer tools to see the output.

Comment: The only thing that appeared in the console was: e0:   then the file and line of code the console.log e0 is on and e1: with the file and line of code.

Comment: Hmmm, Ok. It's almost as if e[0] would have 'O' and e[1] would have 'K', to make the "OK", or at least one of the two would have OK, then we could work around it.  Can you see what the form's action file is, and then see how that might be returning the data?  I don't know if adding a `console.log('e: ' + e);` will be helpful, or not, but you could try that too, though I believe that it might only show 'object'. These console statements are inside the done function, before the 'if' though, correct?

Comment: Let's just try the console log of 'e'. I'm curious if that simply has the OK, because your message earlier had `Error: OK`, where the 'e' was the OK portion, so that would be good to know.

Comment: That just gave me the same: e and then the file and code line. And the same error message when sending.

Comment: Error message when sending?

Comment: Saying "that just gave me the same" is not exactly helpful as many factors could be causing this issue. Personally I'd suggest you replace `e[0] + e[1] == "OK"` with `e.indexOf('OK') === 0` since they essentially do the same thing.

Comment: @SaRay: Well, then make the if condition look like this for a test:  `if (/*e[0] + e[1]*/ e == "OK") {` ... go ahead and remove the console logs since they're not being helpful.